# Optimize my code or get out this process without charge as much RAM?

Tags: raster, layers, memory

I'm working with script code in python for some processes from raster layers, my code takes the raster files, create arrays of data, manipulate the data and then creates a rater output with the results. My problem is, this process much load my ram and my computer dies. I'm working with basins and therefore a large amount of data in each array. I want to know if there is some other way to optimize my code or get out this process without charge as much RAM?

I'm working with the kinematic wave method to determine the runoff of a basin, I am using the explicit method for resolution (The Lax-Wendroff scheme)

This is my Code:

```
import arcpy , numpy , math
from arcpy import env
from fractions import Fraction
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
env.workspace = "C:/data"

#I give the program input values, a raster layer of Slope,
#a raster layer of Aspect, a number of iterations determined by the user
#and an address output to keep the output raster (I do not know what kind 
#of data is the address and I have to put it as "any value")


Slope   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Aspect  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
ii = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

#I create 9 arrays, each represents a variable of the method (which 
#varies for each cell according to variable)


# Array of the Slope data
S_raster=arcpy.Raster(Slope)
S_array=arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(S_raster) 


# Array of the Aspect data
A_raster=arcpy.Raster(Aspect)
A_array=arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(A_raster)


#Array created as a copy of "A_array" to modify their values later
AX_array=arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(A_raster)

#Array created as a copy of "A_array" to modify their values later
AY_array=arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(A_raster)


#Array created as a copy of "A_array" to modify their values later
N_array=arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(A_raster)

#n is the constant Manning roughness of the surface runoff in this case
#will be constant, for more general future cases, this value should be
#associated with the use of land in each cell

n=0.014

#Array created as a copy of "A_array" to modify their values later
H_array=arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(A_raster)

#h0 is the height of water in the initial step, approximately zero

h0=0.00001

#Array created as a copy of "A_array" to modify their values later
Q_array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(A_raster) 


#Array created as a copy of "A_array" to modify their values later
Dt_array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(A_raster) 
CFL=0.5   # constant used in the method

#Array created as a copy of "S_array" to modify their values later
R_array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(S_raster) 
r=0.000001  # rainfall intensity used in the method (in mm/hr)



(height, width)=S_array.shape
desc=arcpy.Describe(Slope)
b=desc.meanCellHeight 
dx=desc.meanCellWidth    
g=9.81 #constant of gravity
iterations = int(ii) 



Area=(height + (height*0.07) )*(width + (width*0.07) ) 
qmx=Area*r
qmx=Fraction(qmx)
expo=Fraction('3/5')
qmxx= qmx ** expo
n=Fraction(n)
expo=Fraction('3/5')
nn= n ** expo
s=S_array.max()
expo=Fraction('0.3')
ss= (s/100) ** expo
Max=(qmxx*nn)/ss  #This is maximum flow possible by an approximation by rational method


#This "for" modify the values in the arrangements created for use
for row in range(0,height):
  for col in range(0,width):

    #Insert data into Water Height Array
    H_array.itemset((row,col),h0)

    #Insert data into Roughness Array
    N_array.itemset((row,col),n)

    #Insert data into rain intensity Array
    R_array.itemset((row,col),r)

    #Insert data into X and Y Arrays of Aspect
    x=numpy.sin(math.radians(A_array.item(row,col)))
    AX_array.itemset((row,col),x)
    y=numpy.cos(math.radians(A_array.item(row,col)))
    AY_array.itemset((row,col),y)

    #It verified that the slope values are nonnegative
    s=S_array.item(row,col)
    if s<0:
     s=0
    else:
     s=s
    S_array.itemset((row,col),s)



#This "for" makes the first step in the method
for row in range(0,height):
  for col in range(0,width):

    #Calculation data of flow array 
    n=N_array.item(row,col)
    h=H_array.item(row,col)
    s=S_array.item(row,col)
    h=Fraction(h)
    expo=Fraction('5/3')
    hh=h ** expo
    s=Fraction(s)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    ss=((s/100) ** expo)
    q=((b/n)*hh*ss) #Manning formula
    Q_array.itemset((row,col),q)

    #Calculation data of delta time array
    h=Fraction(h)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    hh=h ** expo
    g=Fraction(g)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    gg=g ** expo
    dt=CFL*(dx/(gg*hh))
    Dt_array.itemset((row,col),dt)
    minDt = Dt_array.min()


#This "for" makes the other steps in the calculation
for iter in range (0,iterations):

 for row in range(0,height):
   for col in range(0,width):

    #Calculation data of water height  
    ha=H_array.item(row,col)
    r=R_array.item(row,col)
    q=Q_array.item(row,col)


    #These "if´s" checked which of the four cells around each cell   
    #provide water or not to the cell in question

    if row-1 >= 0:
     if AY_array.item(row-1,col) < 0:
      q1 = AY_array.item(row-1,col)*Q_array.item(row-1,col)
     else:
      q1 = 0
    else:
     q1=0
    if col-1 >= 0 :
     if AX_array.item(row,col-1) > 0:
      q2 = AX_array.item(row,col-1)*Q_array.item(row,col-1)
     else:
      q2 = 0
    else:
     q2 = 0   
    if col+1 < width  :
     if AX_array.item(row,col+1) < 0:
      q3 = AX_array.item(row,col+1)*Q_array.item(row,col+1)
     else:
      q3 = 0
    else:
      q3 = 0
    if row+1 < height  :
     if AY_array.item(row+1,col) > 0:
      q4 = AY_array.item(row+1,col)*Q_array.item(row+1,col)
     else:
      q4 = 0
    else:
     q4 = 0

    h=ha+minDt*(r-((q+(q1-q2+q3-q4))/dx))

    if h>0:
     h=h
    else:
     h=0.000000000000000001
    if h>Max:
     h=Max
    else :
     h=h

    H_array.itemset((row,col),h)

 for row in range(0,height):
  for col in range(0,width):

    #Calculation data of flow array 
    n=N_array.item(row,col)
    h=H_array.item(row,col)
    s=S_array.item(row,col)
    h=Fraction(h)
    expo=Fraction('5/3')
    hh=h ** expo
    s=Fraction(s)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    ss=((s/100) ** expo)
    q=((b/n)*hh*ss)
    Q_array.itemset((row,col),q)

    #Calculation data of delta time array
    h=Fraction(h)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    hh=h ** expo
    g=Fraction(g)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    gg=g ** expo
    dt=CFL*(dx/(gg*hh))
    Dt_array.itemset((row,col),dt)
    minDt = Dt_array.min()


#Create the raster with final data flow
C_Cau = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(Q_array,None,1)
C_Cau.save(Output)
```

Comment: itd be easier to tell if you pasted the code here

Comment: You could try using PCRaster (and its associated python lib), which will do what you want to do with very similar code.  I think it would run considerably faster and more reliably than your home-brewed solution.  It is also designed to model things exactly like what you want to do.

http://pcraster.geo.uu.nl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit slower, but better for memory optimization.
Right now, you are creating all your arrays at once at the beginning of your script, two copies of Slope (S, R) and six copies of Aspect (A, AX, AY, N, H, Q, Dt), all as numpy arrays. That is a lot of memory usage!

For three of these arrays (H, N, R) you immediately fill the array with a constant value and never use these arrays for matrix math. Q you use for an intermediate result. Dt ends up being a constant array as well, though calculated from other constant arrays.

And then you use those results to build four new arrays for every item in the original arrays!

First off, iterate the arrays as scalars instead of arrays. Instead of:

```
for row in range(0, height):
    for col in range(0, width):
        _array.itemset((row,col)), value)
```

Use:

```
itemset = _array.itemset #Assigning method to local variable for performance
for i in range(0,_array.size):
    _array.itemset(i, value)
```

You can similarly reference other arrays as:

```
other_array.item(i)
```

instead of:

```
other_array.item((row, col))
```

Or even better, if I want to do a calculation of _array based on other_array:

```
otheritem = other_array.item
itemset = _array.itemset
for i in range(0,_array.size):
    itemset(i, somecalc(otheritem(i))
```

Next, stop using arrays for constants and stop building constants inside loops. For example, this section:

```
for row in range(0,height):
  for col in range(0,width):
    #Calculo de Arreglo de caudal  
    n=N_array.item(row,col)
    h=H_array.item(row,col)
    s=S_array.item(row,col)
    h=Fraction(h)
    expo=Fraction('5/3')
    hh=h ** expo
    s=Fraction(s)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    ss=((s/100) ** expo)
    q=((b/n)*hh*ss)
    Q_array.itemset((row,col),q)
    #Calculo de Arreglo de delta tiempo
    h=Fraction(h)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    hh=h ** expo
    g=Fraction(g)
    expo=Fraction('1/2')
    gg=g ** expo
    dt=CFL*(dx/(gg*hh))
    Dt_array.itemset((row,col),dt)
    minDt = Dt_array.min()
```

Could be rewritten as this:

```
# Already assigned constants
# n = 0.014
# h0 = 0.00001
# b = 1
# g = 9.81
# CFL = 0.5
# dx = 1
# S_array is the modified slope array

hhq = Fraction(h0) ** Fraction('5/3')
hhdt = Fraction(h0) ** Fraction('1/2')
gg = g ** Fraction('1/2')
minDt = CFL * dx / (gg * hhdt) #Since Dt_array is built only from constants, its value is constant
S_item = S_array.item
Q_itemset = Q_array.itemset
for i in range(0, S_array.size):
    ss = ((Fraction(S_item(i))/100) ** Fraction('1/2'))
    q = b * hhq * ss / n
    Q_itemset(i, q)
```

That just cut out N_array, H_array, and Dt_Array.
But there is still a better way to do this. You have a matrix, so use matrix math.

```
# Same constants as above by change ints to floats, e.g.
# b = 1.0 
# dx = 1.0
# I retained using Fraction because it gives higher precision

minDt = CFL * dx / (g ** Fraction('1/2') * h0 ** Fraction('1/2'))
Q_array = b * h0 ** Fraction('5/3') * (S_array/100.0) ** Fraction('1/2') / n
```

I am not going to rewrite the whole program at this point, but hopefully that gives you the right principles to do this better?

Comment: OK, first thanks for the tips. 
I just re-comment the code to improve a little understanding.
  1) In this example, R and N are constant, but for more general cases, N is a raster related to the use of land and R is a raster obtained by interpolation of data obtained from weather stations. So they are actually variables
2) H and Dt are constant only in the first iteration, after this, these arrangements vary

Comment: That helps some. In that case, you will need to be careful about building arrays only when needed and deleting them when you are done with them. I'll look through the code some more and see what I can find. You can also write your arrays to disk in between steps so that you only keep the array you immediately need for calculation (much slower though).